# Rewriting the deprecated code

Tags: php

this line of code is to create a thumb object, but there are warning in php 5.3.x

*"Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated"*

```
if (FALSE === ($thumb =& new thumbnail_party(500, 500, '#FFFFFF', 'jpg', CACHE_PATH))) {
```

how to rewrite it without any warnings?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php 5.3.x you don't need to specify the `&`, found your answer here: http://thinkinglemur.com/index.php/2009/07/assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference-is-deprecated/

so you can just use this:

```
 (FALSE === ($thumb = new thumbnail_party(500, 500, '#FFFFFF', 'jpg', CACHE_PATH))) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove & character referencing is not needed anymore. It's already passed by reference by default.

Comment: nit-picking: http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.references : "One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true."

Answer (score 1):

```
if(false === ($thumb = new thumbnail_party(500, 500, '#FFFFFF', 'jpg', CACHE_PATH))){
    // ...
}
```

However, the `new` operator will never result in `false`, so the check is largely pointless.

If `thumbnail_party` is a class you have control over, consider throwing an exception from the constructor instead:

```
try{
    $thumb = new thumbnail_part(/* ... */);
}catch(Exception $exception){
    // failed to create $thumb
}
```